# Print Fibonacci number

Tags: java, numbers, fibonacci

My program is supposed to output a Fibonacci number based on what the user has entered (ex. if they enter 7 the program will output 13). This portion works. The part I am having trouble with is when the program checks to makes sure the number the user entered was positive and less than or equal to 70. It it supposed to ask the user for input again, but instead it outputs "Fibonacci #-1 is 0" and stops. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class scalvert_Fibonacci
{
public static void main ( String args[] ) 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner ( System.in );

    int sum = 0;
    int num;
    int f1 = 0, f2 = 0, f3 = 1;

    System.out.print("Which Fibonacci number would you like? ");
    num = input.nextInt(); 

    if (num == 0)
    return 0;

    else if (num == 1)
    return 1;

    while (num < 0 || num > 70)
    {
        System.out.print("Which Fibonacci number would you like? ");
        num = input.nextInt(); 
    }

        for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
        {
                f1 = f2;
                f2 = f3;
                f3 = f1 + f2;
        }
        System.out.printf("Fibonacci #%d is %d\n",num, f2);
}
}
```

Comment: There are other problems with your code you should not return any value when return type is "void". Are you able to compile this?

Answer (score 0):

using this might solve your problem

```
if(num<0 || num>70)
{
    //ask a number again
}
else
{
    //calculate
}

or use this

if( 0 < num < 71 )
{
    //calculate
}
else
{
     //ask for a valid number
}
```

Comment: That did work, however after I enter an invalid number twice, it ends the program. Also, if I enter an invalid number, then a valid one, it still ends with no output.

Comment: using return with in your if, **might** solve your problem..(I am not sure about it).. Further you can go side ways that is check for valid inputs.

Comment: Place the if (num==0) return 0; within?

Comment: That gave me the original problem

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
while(num < 0 || num > 70)
    {
        System.out.print("Which Fibonacci number would you like? ");
        num = input.nextInt(); 
    }
```